# How to provide saas customer with server snapshot for business continuity concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, saas

I'm proposing a SaaS solution to a prospective client to avoid the need for local installation and upgrades. The client uploads their input data as needed and downloads the outputs, so data backup and maintenance is not an issue, but continuity of the online software service is a concern for them.

Code escrow would appear to be overkill here and probably of little value. I was wondering is there an option along the lines of providing a snapshot image of a cloud server that includes a working version of the app, and for that to be in the client's possession for use in an emergency where they can no longer access the software.

This would need to be as close to a point and click solution as possible - say a one page document with a few steps that a non web savvy IT person can follow - for starting up the backup server image and being able to use the app. If I were to create a private AWS EBS snapshot / AMI that includes a working version of the application, and they created an AWS account for themselves, might they be able to kick that off easily enough?

Update:the app is on heroku at the moment so hopefully it'd be pretty straightforward to get it running in amazon EC2.

Comment: You can create an AMI and share it with other accounts. Using that AMI, they should be able to launch it immediately. They will not be able to download or transfer it off of aws, at least not very easily.

Comment: That sounds absolutely perfect. Time to port to EC2 and test out the process, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host their app at any major PAAS providers, such as EngineYard or Heroku.  Check their code into a private Github repository that you can assign them as the owner.  That way they have access to the source code and can create a new instance quickly using the repository as the source.

I don't see the need to create an entire service mirror for a Rails app, unless there are specific configuration needs that can't be contained in the project or handled through capistrano.

Comment: The client isn't a tech co so a git repo wouldn't be much use to them and I'd prefer not to give them up front access to the source code.